# How to retrieve an InputStream from SmbRemoteFileTemplate?

Tags: spring-integration

I'm using spring integration for SMB to store and retrieve files from windows server.
In cases when I want to retrieve the file from the server I found the method "get" which receives a lamda function to handler the InputStream, but I need return this element and I wouldn't like to store in local and then return the InputStream. 
Is there any alternative for this matter?

Thank you all.

My code is like this:

```
@Override
    protected InputStream readMetadataFile(final String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        final File inputFile = new File(filename);
        if (this.smbRemoteFileTemplate.exists(filename)) {
            this.smbRemoteFileTemplate.get(filename, in -> FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(in, inputFile));
            return new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

PS: does any mate with reputation greater than 1500 could create the tag "spring-integration-smb"? Thanks again.

Comment: No, no one is not going to create `spring-integration-smb` SO tag. This is really an overhead with such a granulation in questions. The `spring-integration` is fully enough to determine a context for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RemoteFileTemplate` is based on the `SessionFactory` and there is an API like this:

```
/**
 * Obtain a raw Session object. User must close the session when it is no longer
 * needed.
 * @return a session.
 * @since 4.3
 */
Session<F> getSession();
```

That `Session` has this one for you:

```
/**
 * Retrieve a remote file as a raw {@link InputStream}.
 * @param source The path of the remote file.
 * @return The raw inputStream.
 * @throws IOException Any IOException.
 * @since 3.0
 */
InputStream readRaw(String source) throws IOException;
```

Let's hope that this path is enough for your use-case!

Note: that you are responsible for closing this `InputStream` after using.